# Format a string as American

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL below:

```
select cast('13/01/2015' as datetime)
```

The error is: 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'.  I know I can do this  will resolve it:

```
select cast('01/13/2015' as datetime)
```

Is there a way of formatting a string of: '13/01/2015' as '01/13/2015'

Comment: do you want to convert a string to date with a particular format? or get a date as a string with a specific format?

Comment: What, exactly, makes this date "American"?

Comment: @Ellesedil, Because most countries don't format their dates in month/day/year format. Mostly it is America that does that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cast, use [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). this way you can choose the date format.

```
select convert(datetime, '13/01/2015', 103)

select convert(datetime, '01/13/2015', 101)
```

Comment: On top of what Zohar said, here is a good write up about datetime datatypes.

http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dateformat and do something like

```
set dateformat dmy

select cast('13/01/2015' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,'13/01/2015',103),101))
```

This will convert the string to a date time in the format of DD/MM/YYYY, and then it will convert it to the MM/DD/YYYY format you are looking for.

Edit Note: I noticed you wanted the resultant in a string.

Comment: There is no meaning to the format when the data type is date. sql server does not save dates as a formatted string, but as a floating point number. it would be meaningful if the second convert was to char(10).

Comment: Absolutely right! My edit to my post may not be perfect, but it can be adjusted to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CONVERT, but if you choose to use CAST then you might want to try this...

```
SET LANGUAGE british
SELECT CAST('13/01/2015' AS Datetime)

SET LANGUAGE us_english
SELECT CAST('01/13/2015' AS Datetime)
```

This still wont fix your formatting issue though. That's why I would use ..

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/13/2015',101)
```